# Subset sum with recursion - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to solve this problem to practice thinking recursively: given a target number and an array of numbers, find out if there is a combination of the array elements that sums up to the target number. I'm new to this and I have tried everything that I can think of. Is there a problem with my logic or am I forgetting something simple? Here is my code:

```
function findSolution(target, arr){

  function getSum(total, num) {
    return total + num;
  }

  function find(current, push, target, i){
    current.push(push);

    if (current.reduce(getSum) === target){
      return true;
    } else if (current.length >= arr.length){
      return null;
    } else {
      return find(current, arr[i], target, i+1) || 
             find(current, 0, target, i+1);
    }

  }

return find([], 0, target, 0);

return false;
}


console.log(findSolution(23, [4, 6, 10, 1, 3] ));
```

The above target and array should return true (4+6+10+3) but it is returning null. 
Thank you very much for you help :)

Comment: Where does `current.reduce(getSum)` use `i` and where do you reduce the lenght of `current`. Du you use a debugger? You should,

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you should pass a copy of `current` to `find` because you seem to call `find` again if the first call is not `true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take a copy of `current` and you need to return the array with the values. Unfortunately, you add too much zeros to the result set.

Therefore I suggest to add a value at the place of calling the function `find`.

You could omit `target` in `find`, because you have already a closure over it.

```js
function findSolution(target, arr) {
    function getSum(total, num) {
        return total + num;
    }

    function find(current, i) {
        if (current.reduce(getSum, 0) === target) { // initialValue for empty arrays
            return current;
        }
        if (i >= arr.length) {
            return null;
        } 
        return find(current.concat(arr[i]), i + 1)
            || find(current, i + 1);
    }

    return find([], 0);
}

console.log(findSolution(23, [4, 6, 10, 1, 3]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate all possible combinations of the value array to find all solutions:

```js
function findSolution(target, arr) {
 
 const combinations = set => set.reduce(
    (subsets, value) => [
      ...subsets,
      ...subsets.map(subset => [value, ...subset])
    ], 
    [ [] ]
  )

  const getSum = (total, num) => total + num

  return combinations(arr).find(current =>
    current.reduce(getSum, 0) === target
  )
}

console.log(findSolution(23, [4, 6, 10, 1, 3]))
```